# crystal report hide border in print

Tags: crystal-reports

When I am trying to take print (using Print option of Crystal Report Viewer), it shows borders around Subreports. What should I do to hide the borders?

Comment: I retagged your question. "Crystal-Reports" is a much more common tag than "Crystal".  You'll get more responses this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the CR Viewer, but when I create new subreports in the CR Developer, borders are added by default.  Turn it off by **right-click->format subreport->border** and set all the **Line Styles** to **none**.